# In typescript, how to sort exactly like MSSQL's 'order by' clause for special characters like * , + - etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, typescript, mssql-jdbc

I have a Angular5 based front-end which needs to show a list of persons. A similar list is shown at the back-end application. Both lists need to be sorted exactly the same. The back-end list is fetched via a query in MSSQL DB which uses an 'order by' clause like this :

```
select * from PERSON where GROUP=1 order by PERSON.LAST_NAME ASC, PERSON.INITIALS ASC, PERSON.PREFIX ASC, PERSON.FIRSTNAME ASC
```

On the frontend, my person model looks like :

```
export interface Person {
  id?: number;
  fullName?: string;
}
```

The fullName here is as per this format : [LastName, Initials Prefix FirstName] eg : Adams, Mr P John.

I am using this method to sort it :

```
public sortByName(aPersonArr: Person[]) {
    aPersonArr.sort((p1, p2) => {
      let name1 = p1.fullName;
      let name2 = p2.fullName;

      // If both names are blank, consider them equal, If one name is blank, place it at the last
      if (!name1 && !name2) {
        return 0;
      } else if (name1 && !name2) {
        return -1;
      } else if (name2 && !name1) {
        return 1;
      }

      name1 = name1.toLowerCase();
      name2 = name2.toLowerCase();

      if (name1 < name2) {
        return -1;
      }

      if (name1 > name2) {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
    });
  }
}
```

But the problem occurs when a person's fullName begins with a special character because SQL Query fetches the names in this order : (Showing only the lastNames here)

```
*Account
,Adams
.Alkin
+Account
-Adams
```

Whereas my typescript code sorts them like this : (Showing only the lastNames here)

```
*Account
+Account
,Adams
-Adams
.Alkin
```

The reason that I need to have this logic at frontend is that many a times my person list is dynamically prepared and needs to be sorted right away. Is there a way to know what exact logic is used by SQL query to compare strings, so that i can use the same in my sorting method.

Comment: The collation of the involved columns define the exact sort order and comparation rules.

Comment: It's using whatever collation the column has, typically something along the lines of `Latin1_General_CI_AS` or one of the older `SQL_*` collations. The newer collations are supplied by Windows, which should mean that SQL Server ultimately devolves to the results of `CompareString[Ex]` or one of the functions wrapping it -- on Windows, that is. I don't know how it works on Linux (though I suspect great care was taken to ensure the results are identical).

Comment: Our backend application runs on 2 types of DB - Oracle and MSSQL. This example was for MSSQL. But the sorting may be different on Oracle DB. In that case, the front-end also needs to adapt accordingly.

Comment: Collation type is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: "But the sorting may be different on Oracle DB." Then you are going to have to know which DB it came from. More simply, you might be able to figure out a collation for both DBs that matches the typescript `<`

Comment: If you're working across RDBMSes then your only realistic recourse is to let the database do all the actual sorting (possibly by suppying it a list of values through a table parameter, for example), or else accept that the results won't always match exactly. It would be folly to write code that has to detect what database and collation is in use just so it can mimic the sorting algorithms. I suppose you could also make your comparison strictly by ordinal, and enforce this on your database too (`Latin1_General_BIN`), but this tends to be very end-user unfriendly.